# Java call function from a dll

Tags: java, python-3.x, dll, java-native-interface

I have this python script that imports a `zkemkeeper` dll and connects to a time attendance device(`ZKTeco`). Here is is a script I'm using:

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch

zk = Dispatch("zkemkeeper.ZKEM")
zk.Connect_Net("192.168.0.17", 4370)
print(zk.StartIdentify())
print(zk.StartEnrollEx(7, 2, 1))
```

This works fine as expected. However I want to achieve the same using java. How can I call that `Connect_Net` method?
I tried the following in java but didn't work:

```
public class ZKEM {

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("zkemkeeper");
    }

    ZKEM() {
    }

    public static native boolean Connect_Net(String IPAdd, int Portl);

}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.err.println(ZKEM.Connect_Net("192.168.0.17", 4370));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The two choices for calling native code from Java are [JNI (Java Native Interface)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/specs/jni/index.html) and [JNA (Java Native Access)](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna)

The Java runtime can do JNI out of the box, but you need to create a wrapper library with functions specifically made for JNI (just putting in a `native` keyword is not enough).

JNA is a 3rd party library that uses [libffi](https://sourceware.org/libffi/) to make native code accessible from Java.

You have to see for yourself which approach better suits your needs.

Edit: looking at your example code again, is that a COM call? While COM can be done with JNA (doing that myself), it's quite complicated. Your best bet is probably a wrapper C library that does the actual calls or a Java/COM bridge product like [JACOB](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jacob-project/) (have never used it, however).

Comment: Thanks although I had tried JNI but wasn't successful. Do you have an example with JNI?

Comment: Your try with JNI was not successful because you have to write the needed wrapper library first. I don't have an example ready because I'm using JNA for native access, but there's lots of tutorials out there (basically it's: write a Java class, compile, call `javah` on the class, implement the functions that are in the generated header). Microsoft has documentation about how to use COM from C, but if you're not familiar with that, maybe a using COM bridge library will be best

Answer (score 1):

Although this is an old post, I am finalizing a pure Java ZKEM:
https://github.com/mkhoudary/ZKTeco4J

I was using ZKemKeeper DLL with COM4J in the past:
https://github.com/mkhoudary/ZKEMJavaPort

But the pure Java one is really robust, you may watch the repo, I am in the final stages