# How to call dll files in java

Tags: java, dll, java-native-interface, dllimport, advapi32

I need to call a DLL file **advapi32.dll** in java so that i can use its **CryptEncrypt** function for Encryption. Is it possible to access the functions of the dll files through JNI or is there any other better ways

> advapi32.dll is found in system32 folder of windows

I tried using

```
System.loadLibrary("advapi32");
```

and

```
Runtime.getRuntime().loadLibrary("C:/Windows/System32/crypt32.dll");
```

Runtime.getRuntime().loadLibrary() giving the following errors

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no C:/Windows/System32/crypt32.dll in java.library.path
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
at mail.encrypt.main(encrypt.java:17)
```

Comment: What the possible ways to do X is a question that doesn't our mold here on SO.

Comment: See my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52944462/java-call-function-from-a-dll/52948018#52948018 (the edit of course doesn't apply to your question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the lib path using below command

```
java -Djava.library.path=C:/Windows/System32/
```

Or use below hacking way inside code

```
System.setProperty( "java.library.path", "C:/Windows/System32/" );
Field fieldSysPath = ClassLoader.class.getDeclaredField("sys_paths"); 
fieldSysPath.setAccessible( true ); 
fieldSysPath.set( null, null );
```